# Identifying the name of a class during run time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, class

So I have run into a fairly complex problem with my application.
I have about 40 UIImageView objects that need to be displayed at different locations when different ones are stacked (EX img 1 needs to take img 2 place if img2 ==NO).

What I am trying to do is use a "for loop" and run through all my Boolean values that check if the image is selected.
I was curious if it is at all possible to call variable like this

```
-(IBAction) button:(id) sender{
    scrollView.hidden = YES;
    NSInteger i = 1;
    (@"imagenumber%d", i) = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (28, 230, 86, 26)];
    [[imagenumber(@"%d", i)] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"csa.jpg"]];
    [self.view addSubview: [imagenumber(@"%d", i)]];}   
}
```

where @"imagenumber%d" is my NSImageView and i is a number ranging from 1-40.

I'm sorry if this is confusing, I really would appreciate any help at all on the subject because I can’t seem to get any idea and have been working on this problem for several weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the views in a `NSMutableArray` - you can access elements in those by index, use fast enumeration, ... E.g.:

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] ...
[myMutableArray addObject:image];
// ...
```

Comment: huh, never thought to do that,
I think that will work thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of hilarity you could also put them in a intrinsic array and use pointer arithmetic. (Which is probably what happens behind the scenes with faster enumeration for those interested)

```
UIImageView * imageArray[40];

...

for(UIImageView * this = imageArray; this; this++)
{
    this = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (28, 230, 86, 26)];
    ...
}
```